# How can I use willSet in a UIViewController property

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to play a little bit with swift and iOS 8.

The question is, I'm trying to create this setter in a view controller:

```
- (void)setViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    _viewController = viewController;
    method do something
}
```

This code below is in Objective-C so I'd like to create it in swift.

I think, I should use willSet, but I know how do it if it's defined when you have your own variable, how can I define that willSet method if that property is a ViewController property.

Thanks

Comment: @Eric has the right approach. In this case though, if you want code to execute after setting the viewController, you probably want to use didSet instead.

Comment: Addendum to @Kamaros comment: you can use both `willSet` and `didSet` - one doesn't exclude the other

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
var viewController: UIViewController? {
    willSet {
        //method to do something
    }
}
```

You can actually access what viewController will be set to with the variable "newValue" if you need that in the method call.

Note: I made the property optional here just to get rid of compiler warnings about needing initialization

Answer (score -1):

An alternate way different from @Eric's answer is by using a computed property, which mimics objective-c properties more closely, consisting on defining a pseudo-private data member and a computed property implementing a getter and a setter:

```
class MyClass {
    var _viewController: UIViewController?

    var viewController : UIViewController? {
        get {
            return self._viewController
        }

        set {
            self._viewController = newValue
            // Do something else
        }
    }
}
```

I defined the property *pseudo-private* because swift doesn't have access modifiers (yet), so everything is public - but when I see an underscore prefixing a variable or property name, that to me means private (It's a convention I use it a lot in javascript for instance).

Comment: Please share with us the reason for **downvoting** - if the code doesn't work, it would be good to know why.

Comment: I thought so... the comment is addressed to whoever did the downvote. I'm not against downvotes, everybody can make mistakes, and I appreciate when constructive feedback is done and when errors I make are highlighted.

Comment: I totally agree but I reckon your way it's little bit odd, but I think works perfectly, thanks

Comment: It's not much different than creating properties in objective-c without using the @syntesize (you had to create setter and getter), and with syntax not much dissimilar from how they are handled in C# (when not using auto properties). Actually that is a pattern that I am actively using on a project